# My implementation of reservoir implementation

Tags: java, random

Hello， based on the weki description of the reservoir sampling algorithm, I did this, and it seems not working as expected. The algorithm is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Where it's possibly wrong?

```
public int[] sample(int k, int[] array) {

    int[] reservior = new int[k];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<k; i++){
        reservior[i] = array[i];
    }

    int j=0;
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for(; i<array.length; i++){
        j = random.nextInt(i);

        if(j< k){
            reservior[j] = array[i];
        }
    }

    return reservior;
}
```

This is my testing code. I created an array with elements from 0 ... 9, and call the function "sample(k,array)" with K=5. One run of this looks below. Clearly it's not random with equal probability.

0 9 2 3 5

0 9 2 3 5

0 6 8 7 4

0 6 8 7 4

0 6 8 7 4

0 6 8 7 4

0 6 8 7 4

0 6 8 7 4

0 6 8 7 4

0 6 8 7 4

```
    int size = 10;      
    int[] array = new int[size];

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }

    int k = 5;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        int[] reservior = sample(k, array);
        for(int j=0; j<reservior.length; j++){
            System.out.print(reservior[j] + " ");

        }   
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling sample so quickly that it's seeded with the same value for several runs. That's why you see the values eventually do change, just not with every call.

You might make random a private class variable so that it's only seeded once (and you don't need to seed it yourself...by default it will use System.nanoTime() which would make this *less* of an issue on its own). This solution also saves a little bit of memory and a few CPU cycles spent needlessly initializing a new instance of Random.

```
public class ReservoirExample {
  private Random random = new Random();

  public int[] sample(int k, int[] array) {

    int[] reservior = new int[k];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<k; i++){
      reservior[i] = array[i];
    }

    int j=0;
    for(; i<array.length; i++){
      j = random.nextInt(i);

      if(j< k){
        reservior[j] = array[i];
      }
    }

    return reservior;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the same value for more than one millisecond (typically, 10 milliseconds on a Windows machine).

And Random is a **pseudo** random generator. So, if you create a Random and seed it with a given value, it will give a deterministic sequence of values. Since you always recreate it and seed it with the same value, you always get the same sequence of values.

Use a unique instance of Random, created once, and not seeded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, following the suggestion above, I　ｒｕｎ　ｔｈｅ　ｓａｍｐｌｅ（）　10000　ｔｉｍｅｓ， and got these numbers. The first column is the integer, and the second column represents the number of times sampled for this integer in this 1000 calls of the function. It still seems not evenly distributed random sampling of the integers in the array.

I am not sure whether the implementation of the algorithm has some problem, or something else.

1 4445

2 4390

3 4548

4 4435

5 5588

6 5505

7 5560

8 5553

9 5559